# A Generalization of Linear Functions. But is it Useful?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space, and let $Y$ be another normed vector space over the same scalar field. Let $\|\cdot\|$ denote the norm of $Y$.

We say that a function $g: X \to Y$ is **quasi-linear** if there exists a $C>0$ such that

> $\|g(x+y)\| \leq C(\|g(x)\|+\|g(y)\|)$ ${}$ and ${}$ $\|g(\alpha x)\| = |\alpha|\|g(x)\|$

for all vectors $x$ and scalars $\alpha$.

My question concerns the class of functions $g : X \to Y$ for which there exists a $C>0$ such that

> $\|g(x+y)\| \leq C(\|g(x)+g(y)\|)$ ${}$ and ${}$ $\|g(\alpha x)\| = |\alpha|\|g(x)\|$

for all vectors $x$ and scalars $\alpha$ (note, the value of $C$ is allowed to depend on the particular function $g$).

First, **does the latter class of functions have a name?** Second, observe that we have the containments
$$
    \text{linear functions} \subseteq \text{this class of functions} \subseteq \text{quasi-linear functions}
$$
so that my other question is **is either of these containments strict?**

Thanks very much.

Comment: I mean that $C$ can depend on $g$, and I edited the question to hopefully clarify this. The rest of your question I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @snulty I don't believe so; maybe I'm misunderstanding you? After all, Luiz Cordeiro, in their answer, gave an example of a function that is quasi-linear but not in the latter class of functions.

Comment: Ah those extra norm brackets were just invisible to be for some reason.  I don't know why visually $\|g(x)\|+\|g(y)\|$ and $\|g(x)+g(y)\|$ just looked the same. I might need new glasses :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $g\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x\neq 2\\-2&\text{ if }x=2\end{cases}$$
is quasi-linear (it preserves norm/absolute value), but
$$|g(1+2)|=|g(3)|=3$$
whereas
$$|g(1)+g(2)|=|1-2|=1$$
so it is not in your class of functions.

Comment: Good example! Thanks. If our new class of functions is not just the linear functions (surely it is not), do you have any suggestions as to a name for this class of functions?

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman It doesn't seem like your definition of "quasilinear" matches the one in Wikipedia, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function. I'm also not sure if there is standard terminology for this. I think it is better to use more self-explanatory terminology. For example, I'd call the property "$\Vert g(\alpha x)\Vert=|\alpha|\Vert g(x)\Vert$" absolute norm-homogeneity; the condition on sums for quasilinearity could be "weak norm-subadditivity", and the condition on your class of functions could be "strong norm-subadditivity".

Comment: @ThomasWinckelman Even better, just call one of them "quasilinear" and the other one "weakly" or "strongly" quasilinear (whatever appropriate) and indicate to your reader that this terminology is not standardized.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Oh, and, my definition of quasi-linearity is from **Grafakos** *Classical Fourier Analysis* 3e (equation 1.3.4, page 33, section 1.3).